# Replacing @Autowired Httpservlet and why isn't it a good practice to Autowired httpservlet in springbok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, autowired

I have been told that it is not a good practice to

`@Autowired 
 HttpServlet httpServlet;`

in spring boot as it will only make a single object for all the hits. I am very new to to Spring Boot and Java, hence I would appreciate if someone can clear this and also suggest a better way of implementation.

Comment: UPDATE : The problem was solved by passing it as parameter! 
TIP : The code with request as parameter is difficult to mock, so i replaced it with (_) wherever the request was being passed in mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually inject `HttpServletRequest` as method param:

```
public SomeResponseObject someMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: can you suggest if there is a way to mock this request?

Comment: As any other request. You can use mocito . And mock .

Comment: @D_millio.naiR can you mark my comment as solution then ? Thx